# Using ArrayList as function call Java

Tags: java, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

```
public class TestClass extends BaseClass {
    public void getquote() {
        String FirstName = "Sam";
        String LastName = "Gayle";
        String Email = "somename@somename.com";
        String Password = "test1234";
        CallGetQuote(FirstName, LastName, Email, Password);
}

private void CallGetQuote(String... var) {
    for (int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("first-name")).sendKeys(var[i]);
        driver.findElement(By.id("last-name")).sendKeys(var[i]);
        driver.findElement(By.id("join-email")).sendKeys(var[i]);
        driver.findElement(By.id("join-password")).sendKeys(var[i]);
        // driver.findElement(By.name("btn-submit")).click();
    }
}
```

}

`I would like to fill in the objects using a loop rather than hard coded index number as mentioned. Above is what I wrote, at the moment, all text boxes are filling with all values. Please help :(

Thanks.`

Comment: Are you looking for a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)? It's hard to tell what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually I am learning some UI automation using selenium & need to pass few values to fill in objects on a form. The number of arguments might change in future if more objects are added to the form.

Comment: @user3325340 if any answer solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Comment: @user3325340 if you are using some library other thank Java, (selenium?), please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: You must not copy an answer at each time and make it a question, this is an other request and we have no way how to know that you are asking a new one, please next time either continue asking in comments or make a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `varargs`, more informations could be found in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> You can use a construct called varargs to pass an arbitrary number of
>   values to a method. You use varargs when you don't know how many of a
>   particular type of argument will be passed to the method.

So, your code will be something like:

```
    public void getquote() {

        String firstName = "Sam";
        String lastName = "Gayle";
        String email = "somename@somename.com";
        String password = "test1234";

        CallGetQuote(FirstName, LastName, Email, Password);

    }

    public void CallGetQuote(String... var) {

        // add your elements to a List
        List<MyElements> inputElements = new ArrayList<MyElements>;

        inputElements.add(driver.findElement(By.id("first-name")));
        inputElements.add(driver.findElement(By.id("last-name"))); 
        inputElements.add(driver.findElement(By.id("join-email")));  
        inputElements.add(driver.findElement(By.id("join-password")));

        // iterate over the List to send keys
        for (int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
        inputElements.get(i).sendKeys(var[i]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Since the O.P. probably isn't aware this was possible, it's worth noting that var is treated just like an array.  So you can use things like `var.length` and `var[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

May be instead of passing array/list you can create a class containing all the variable and accessors and modifier functions for each variable. Create the object of the class in getQuote() and append the values in the same function. Later you can simply pass the object.

And whenever you have new attribute you can simply add the attributes to the class and use the object anywhere.

Comment: @Tarik, thanks for the help, I would like to use a loop rather than hard coding index values to fill the text boxes. Please let me know what I am doing wrong in my latest code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

considaring that you have only specified number of inputs on web page you may try like this.

```
public void getquote() {
    String FirstName = "Sam";
    String LastName = "Gayle";
    String ZipCode = "10104";
    String PhoneNumber = "212-225-8558";
    CallGetQuote(FirstName, LastName, ZipCode, PhoneNumber);
}

public void CallGetQuote(String... var) {
    List<Webelement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
    for (int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
        inputs.get(i).sendKeys(var[i]);
    }

}
```

You may have to change the order of strings you are sending.